# Apple Mach-O Linker error after removing a pod (cocoa pods)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, linker, cocoapods

I took over a project from a previous developer using cocoa pods. Now I had to remove a pod and can't compile the project anymore. I removed all imports and references to that pod but I get a linker error.
I get a warning:

```
directory not found for option '-L/Users/UserName/Documents/ProjectName/Pods/TestFlightSDK'
```

and an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_TFLog", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[AppDelegate application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[AppDelegate application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:] in AppDelegate.o
      ___78-[AppDelegate application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:]_block_invoke in AppDelegate.o
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[Layout createTrackHeadingWithDay:track:] in Layout.o
      -[Layout createDayHeadingWithDay:] in Layout.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I found a similar question but it was answered as "not reproducible".
It could be a problem with the inherited other linker flag but I can't see if TestFlight still appear there and I don't know where this $(inherited) is generated.

Comment: You cleaned the project, right?

Comment: that and ran `pod update` after removing the pod from its Podfile?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that. I removed the pod folder and podlist.lock from the project. Then I cleaned the project and the build folder and ran pod install again. Still getting the same error (and also some new shell script invocation errors from missing folder which doesn't seem to interupt the compiling). I should also add that I'm totally unexperienced with OSX, iOS and Xcode. I just shall "clean up" the project to the basic needs and port it to Xamarin.

Comment: any update about problem ?

Comment: Sadly not. We just kept the unused pod in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Check under General -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries  if the .framework is there,if you recently deleted it be sure to remove it from here as well